# How to check existence of a table from a different sql db?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, exists

I have db A and db B. At the beginning of a stored procedure I want to back up all rows from `B.mytable` to `B.mytablebackup`. The rest of the stored procedure runs against tables on db A (which gathers data and writes it to `B.mytable`).

So I check to see if `B.mytablebackup` exists

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B.dbo.mytablebackup)
```

and if it does, the stored procedure does an

```
INSERT INTO B..mytablebackup SELECT * FROM B..mytable
```

If it doesn't exist it does a

```
SELECT * INTO B..mytablebackup from B..mytable
```

But when I execute the stored procedure I get the error

> There is already an object named 'mytablebackup' in the database

I added a `Print` statement and execution is taking the "does not exist" branch of the IF.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: @marc_s I would guess that it's MSSQL based on `db.schema.tbl` format

Comment: `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B.dbo.mytablebackup)` checks whether there is at least one row *within* `mytablebackup`. It doesn't tell you whether the table itself *exists* (if the table doesn't exist, it'll produce a compilation error)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: sure - my guess to - but it would easier if you did **not** have to guess ...

Comment: My apologies: TSQL on Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For SQL Server, you should use system view sys.tables to check if table exists.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B.sys.tables WHERE name = 'mytablebackup')
```

Answer (score 7):

[OBJECT_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql) can be used too:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('B.dbo.mytablebackup') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: that's the correct answer for unknown database name (i'm mean when you want to check based on parameter)

Comment: and one more advantage is that you could use it in UDF

Comment: and you could use COL_LENGTH for columns checking

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check from the given DB,SCHEMA and TABLE parameters (For dynamic database, schema and table use)

```
DECLARE @targetdatabase  NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SchemaName      NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableName       NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @TempTableName NVARCHAR(MAX) = QUOTENAME(@targetdatabase) + '.' + 
QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)

IF OBJECT_ID(@TempTableName) IS NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT @TempTableName
END
```